# How to change the dashboard title and content in the dashboard page in Jmeter 3.0 generated Dashboard

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, security-testing

I want to know how and where to change the dashboard title and other content in jmeter 3.0 generated dashboard

Comment: were you able to generate dynamic title in dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

1. To change the title add the following line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=Your desired title
   ```
2. You cannot change the content as it is being generated from result files. You can tune the representation of the existing content again by manipulating JMeter Properties which names start with `jmeter.reportgenerator.`

References:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for your valuable answer.But here I want to give the name dynamic.How can I achieve it. ex: "Report for 50 Users ...." etc..,